# Nextjs Tailwind Marquee Component is overflowing

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I've created the following nextjs/tailwind component. It's a scrolling isometric marquee component. For some reason I can't get it to stop overflowing to the right. I want the component to be rendered before, because else the marquee wouldnt work, but the page shouldnt be horizontally scrollable to the right.

```jsx
<div class="marquee isometric md:-left-[330px] -left-[130px] mt-[50px] md:mt-[100px] absolute py-8 ">
    <div class="marquee-content scroll">
        <motion.div className="h-[410px] p-4  rounded-xl bg-gray-200">
            <Image src={Gym1} className="object-cover w-full h-full rounded-xl " />
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div className="h-[410px] p-4  rounded-xl bg-gray-200">
            <Image src={Gym2} className="object-cover w-full h-full rounded-xl " />
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div className="h-[410px] p-4  rounded-xl bg-gray-200">
            <Image src={Img3} className="object-cover w-full h-full rounded-xl " />
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div className="h-[410px] p-4  rounded-xl bg-gray-200">
            <Image src={Img4} className="object-cover w-full h-full rounded-xl " />
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div className="h-[410px] p-4  rounded-xl bg-gray-200">
            <Image src={Img5} className="object-cover w-full h-full rounded-xl " />
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div className="h-[410px] p-4  rounded-xl bg-gray-200">
            <Image src={Img6} className="object-cover w-full h-full rounded-xl " />
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div className="h-[410px] p-4  rounded-xl bg-gray-200">
            <Image src={Img7} className="object-cover w-full h-full rounded-xl " />
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div className="h-[410px] p-4  rounded-xl bg-gray-200">
            <Image src={Img8} className="object-cover w-full h-full rounded-xl " />
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div className="h-[410px] p-4  rounded-xl bg-gray-200">
            <Image src={Img9} className="object-cover w-full h-full rounded-xl " />
        </motion.div>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee-content scroll">
        <motion.div className="h-[410px] p-4  rounded-xl bg-gray-200">
            <Image src={Gym1} className="object-cover w-full h-full rounded-xl " />
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div className="h-[410px] p-4  rounded-xl bg-gray-200">
            <Image src={Gym2} className="object-cover w-full h-full rounded-xl " />
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div className="h-[410px] p-4  rounded-xl bg-gray-200">
            <Image src={Img3} className="object-cover w-full h-full rounded-xl " />
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div className="h-[410px] p-4  rounded-xl bg-gray-200">
            <Image src={Img4} className="object-cover w-full h-full rounded-xl " />
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div className="h-[410px] p-4  rounded-xl bg-gray-200">
            <Image src={Img5} className="object-cover w-full h-full rounded-xl " />
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div className="h-[410px] p-4  rounded-xl bg-gray-200">
            <Image src={Img6} className="object-cover w-full h-full rounded-xl " />
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div className="h-[410px] p-4  rounded-xl bg-gray-200">
            <Image src={Img7} className="object-cover w-full h-full rounded-xl " />
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div className="h-[410px] p-4  rounded-xl bg-gray-200">
            <Image src={Img8} className="object-cover w-full h-full rounded-xl " />
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div className="h-[410px] p-4  rounded-xl bg-gray-200">
            <Image src={Img9} className="object-cover w-full h-full rounded-xl " />
        </motion.div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The marquee, marquee-content, scroll and isometric css classes are as follows:

```css
.isometric {
  transform: matrix(1, 0.27, -0.8, 0.7, 0, 0);
}

.marquee {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 150%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
}

.marquee-content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
}

.scroll {
  animation: scroll 65s linear infinite;
}
```

Can someone help me getting it fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider disabling horizontal scrolling on the nearest scrolling parent, such as the `<body>`:

```css
.isometric {
  transform: matrix(1, 0.27, -0.8, 0.7, 0, 0);
}

.marquee {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 150%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
}

.marquee-content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
}

.scroll {
  animation: scroll 65s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<body class="overflow-x-hidden">
  <div class="marquee isometric absolute -left-[130px] mt-[50px] py-8 md:-left-[330px] md:mt-[100px]">
    <div class="marquee-content scroll">
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?0" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?1" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?2" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?3" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?4" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?5" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?6" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee-content scroll">
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?7" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?8" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?9" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?10" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?11" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?12" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?13" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?14" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?15" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Otherwise, you could consider wrapping the markup in a sufficiently tall element that hides any overflow:

```css
.isometric {
  transform: matrix(1, 0.27, -0.8, 0.7, 0, 0);
}

.marquee {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 150%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
}

.marquee-content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
}

.scroll {
  animation: scroll 65s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="relative overflow-hidden h-[600px]">
  <div class="marquee isometric absolute -left-[130px] mt-[50px] py-8 md:-left-[330px] md:mt-[100px]">
    <div class="marquee-content scroll">
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?0" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?1" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?2" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?3" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?4" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?5" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?6" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee-content scroll">
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?7" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?8" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?9" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?10" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?11" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?12" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?13" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?14" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="h-[410px] rounded-xl bg-gray-200 p-4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?15" class="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just added "overflow-x-hidden" to the body element of my nextjs main layout. Thanks.